# "Поп" - это грубая форма или нет?

Tags: этимология, стилистика

Слово "поп" по отношению к священнику является ли грубой формой и откуда оно вообще пошло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, грубым назвать его никак нельзя.
Просто разговорное. Ну до тех пор пока кому-то не вздумается использовать как обращение.
Сейчас приобрело оттенок некоторой вульгарности, презрения или неодобрительности.

В отношении происхождения - достоверных версий нет, Фасмер возводит к германской основе с тем же значением.

Answer (score 4):

ПОП, а́, м. [от греч. pappas].
**1.** Священник (разг. встарину — официальное название). Произнося обет перед налоем, ты солгала попу. А. Островский. Каков поп, таков и приход. Поговорка. Что ни поп, то батька. Поговорка.
|| Вообще — служитель культа всякого ранга (разг. пренебр.).
|| только мн., собир. Духовенство (разг. пренебр.).
**2.** В игре в городки: сбитая рюха, которую вновь ставят стоймя, если она упадет на линии. Сбить попа легко.
◊На попа (ставить, поставить; простореч. и спец.) — стоймя. Поставить кирпич на попа.
[Толковый словарь Ушакова, 1935-1940 г.](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/958906)

О происхождении разные мнения. От  общеславянского до греческого.